# not enough information to infer type variable T1

Tags: kotlin

Can someone help me with why I got an error in the code? I followed exactly as the tutorial
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IprH9.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Insert your code here in `code` format and paste your error in a block too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you did not import the `TextView` correctly, so `findViewById` doesn't know what type of View it is.

Try to import the TextView by right clicking on the red text and picking Import:

[image: Import Dialog]

It should add something like `import android.widget.TextView` at the top (or you can manually do that).

Alternatively, you can tell findViewById which type you want:

`val something = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.xxxxx)`

Or you can do both

`val something: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.xxxxx)`

Of you can do just the type:

`val something: TextView = findViewById(R.id.xxxxx)`

Either works, so as long as the compiler can correctly determine/infer which type of view you are trying to find.

*Next time, please do not include images as part of your question *to replace text*. It's better to copy/paste the relevant parts in Text format, so it's indexed, searchable, and doesn't depend on someone opening an image to see your text (text in images doesn't scale with accessibility, it's not read by screen readers, etc.).*